# "default" is not exported by "tailwind.config.js"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vite, storybook

I want to use a theme variable for Tailwind inside the Nuxt code for Storybook. Everything looks fine in development but when I build Storybook, I get an error `"default" is not exported by "tailwind.config.js"`.

[image]

I tried to follow what is written [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss.com/issues/765) but I still get errors. Could anybody help me with a good solution for this?

vite.config.js

```
import path from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'tailwind.config.js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: [
      'tailwind.config.js',
    ],
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: ['tailwind.config.js', 'node_modules/**'],
    },
  },
})
```

tailwind.config.js

```
// /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      mobileS: '320px',
      mobileM: '375px',
      mobileL: '425px',
      tablet: '500px',
    },
  },
}
```

inside the component

```
import tailwindConfig from 'tailwind.config.js'
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'

const screens = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig).theme?.screens
console.log(screens)
```

Comment: If you use tailwind.config.js as es module then don't define it as commonjs. Did you try to not use module.exports and commonjsOptions?

Comment: Instead of `import` try with `require` - or instead of `module.exports = ` try with `export default`

Answer (score 3):

tailwindcss added native ESM (and TypeScript) support in v3.3.

https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-3#esm-and-type-script-support.

In my case, I migrated the `tailwind.config.js` by changing imports & exports:

**Before:**

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

module.exports = { ... }
```

**After:**

```js
import colors from "tailwindcss/colors";
import plugin from "tailwindcss/plugin";

export default { ... }
```

within my vite codebase, I was then able to access config values like this

```js
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig";

import tailwindConfig from "../../tailwind.config.js";

const { theme } = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);

theme.colors.gray[500]
```

Comment: This answer must be marked as right